# Finding the closest number to a target sum of a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a snippet of code just like this one:

```
import itertools
numbers = [352.07, 15.20, 15.22, 2505.71, 2050.86, 
337.86, 833.90, 314.83]
result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) == 2842.77]
print(result)
```

Essentially it uses the itertool library to take a list of numbers and trying to find  the which of the numbers add up to the sum (in this example it is 2842.77). In this case however, none of the numbers in the list actually add up to the target number.

Is there a any piece of code that I could add so that I can get THE CLOSEST number to the target number if there is no exact match? In this example, I am looking for the console to spit out:

(2505.71, 337.86), closest number: 2843.57

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `min()` to get the sequence that has the smallest absolute difference between the sum and target, e.g. using the `key` parameter to `min()`:

```
import itertools as it

# From itertools recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

In []:
target = 2842.77
result = min(powerset(numbers), key=lambda seq: abs(sum(seq)-target))
result

Out[]:
(2505.71, 337.86)

In []:
sum(result)

Out[]:
2843.57
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution using combinations is fine if your list is small but note that sum of `combinations(number, i)` over all i is `2**len(numbers)`.  This grows very fast and will kill your program.

Your problem is known as "Subset sum" where you want to pick a subset of numbers to sum up to your sum.  It is very well known and has very many variants and solutions.  It is also NP-complete meaning there is no real polynomial (fast) solution for it.

However, there is a pseudopolynomial solution using dynamic programming.

Example here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/